# Sum up a group of rows in the output

Tags: sum

I'm trying to do a sum of a select group of rows.  ex.  I have a warehouse with 10 routes and I would like to sum the total weight of the cases on the truck by route. I have rows listed with the total weight but want to make an extra row with the total.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  It is unclear from your question by what tool or method you are trying to sum your rows.  Is this in a spreadsheet?  Is it written in code?  If code, which programming language?

Comment: apologies.  i am using sql.  here's what i have:

Comment: i have too many characters to enter the whole thing.  but output is

Comment: an entire warehouse w/ multiple routes, need to total the weight in the output of my query for the entire route